# How to configure netty in spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

By default spring web flux uses netty which is single threaded event loop. How to configure spring boot so that a thread will be created for each core.

Thanks,

Lokesh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in the [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-webserver), you can customize the Reactor Netty web server with a `NettyServerCustomizer`.

Here's an example with Spring Boot 2.1:

```
@Component
public class MyNettyWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(new EventLoopNettyCustomizer());
    }
}

class EventLoopNettyCustomizer implements NettyServerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
        LoopResources loopResources = LoopResources.create(...);
        return httpServer.runOn(loopResources);
    }
}
```

Comment: tcpConfiguration deprecated. no alternative provided

Comment: @RamPrakash I've updated my code snippet. A better, shorter and more flexible alternative is provided.

Comment: @BrianClozel Thanks. Can I ask one question related to this? Looks like there is no way to increase the boss thread count. Or boss is renamed to selector?

Answer (score -3):

You can change your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Use Jetty instead -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

Comment: The question is not about changing the server. how to run a single-threaded netty attach to each processor